# QnA & LUIS Chatbot C#

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to implement a QnaMakerDialog after LUIS recognizes that it is a QnA Intent. In my Dialogs folder, I have two files: BasicLuisDialog.cs and BasicQnAMakerDialog.cs. In my Controller, it calls BasicLuisDialog, and I want to call the QnAMakerDialog within that. Here is my full BasicLuisDialog code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;

using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot;




namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.LuisBot
{
    [Serializable]
    public class BasicLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {
        public BasicLuisDialog() : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute("asdf", "asdf")))
//replace asdf with keys 
        {
        }

        [LuisIntent("None")]
        public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"You have reached the none intent. You said: {result.Query}"); //
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }

        [LuisIntent("Weather.GetCondition")]
        public async Task ConditionIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"You have reached the Condition intent. You said: {result.Query}"); //
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }

        [LuisIntent("Weather.GetForecast")]
        public async Task ForecastIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"You have reached the ForecastIntent intent. You said: {result.Query}"); //
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }

        [LuisIntent("GetQnA")]
        public async Task GetQnA(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
        {
        var msg = await activity;
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var faq = new BasicQnAMakerDialog();
        await context.Forward(faq, AfterFAQDialog, msg, CancellationToken.None);

        }

        private async Task AfterFAQDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
        }

    }
}
```

I get the error:

> Dialogs\BasicLuisDialog.cs(51,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BasicQnAMakerDialog' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code for BasicQnAMakerDialog.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker;

namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot
{
    [Serializable]
    public class BasicQnAMakerDialog : QnAMakerDialog
    {
        public BasicQnAMakerDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute("asdf", "asdf","No good match in FAQ",0.2,3))) 
        {
        }

        protected override async Task DefaultWaitNextMessageAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("KB Question: " + results.Answers.First().Questions.First());
            Console.WriteLine("KB Answer: " + results.Answers.First().Answer);
            await base.DefaultWaitNextMessageAsync(context, message, results);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the top of the class? the usings

Comment: using System;  
using System.Configuration;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Web.Http;  
  
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;  
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;  
using System.Web.Http.Description;  
using System.Net.Http;  
using System.Diagnostics;  
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;  
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;

Comment: CancellationToken is in System.Threading, so you should also have "using System.Threading;"  I'm not sure why BasicQnAMakerDialog isn't found.  Please add the entire dialog's code, as it is, to the question.

Comment: Updated. The using System.Threading got rid of the first error.

Comment: What namespace is your `BasicQnAMakerDialog` in?

Comment: It is in namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot - It is in a file named BasicQnAMakerDialog.cs that is in the same folder, Dialogs

Comment: You need to add an using Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot;

Answer (score 0):

Add a `using` for the namespace where the `BasicQnAMakerDialog.cs` is at.

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot
```

Comment: I now have the issue: Dialogs\BasicLuisDialog.cs(14,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'QnABot' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Bot.Sample' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: are these different projects in visual studio?

Comment: They are different .cs files. But they are in the same folder, Dialogs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158721/discussion-between-sharon-fang-and-ezequiel-jadib).